# Meaning of ARM assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

Can anyone please explain what is the meaning of this code for ARM?

```
__asm__ __volatile__("mov %0, pc \n":"=r"(val)::"memory")
```

I think it stores the value of program counter in the variable **val**. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, it puts the program counter into `val`.

The `=r` means that it's an output write-only variable. `"memory"` tells the compiler not to cache values across the inline assembly. I'm not 100% sure why `"memory"` has been used here though.

Comment: memory is used to tell gcc not to cache values and reload them into registers after the inline asm instructions http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3